# How to add native IONIC arrow (tappable) to the ion-row

Tags: html, css, user-interface, ionic-framework, ionic2

Is there any way to add native Ionic 2 right arrow to the `<ion-row>` inside `<ion-grid>` ? I have a grid with few columns and want to use the same arrow UI as Ionic 2 uses for `<button ion-item>`

[image]

Can you please help to find the best solution?
Thanks

Comment: You should add the 'detail-push' attribute directive to the ion-item. Note that iOS would have the arrow by default

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got your question right, but you can do like this:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon> <!-- use the ios one to have this chevron right -->
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

You can make it go to the right with:

- The css `text-align: right;` on the `<ion-icon>`.
- The `text-right` attribute on `<ion-icon>`.
- Or having 2 `<ion-col>`, beeing the second one the one to have the `<ion-icon>` and declared like `<ion-col width-10>`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
ion-row {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg%20xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"%20viewBox="0%200%2012%2020"><path%20d="M2,20l-2-2l8-8L0,2l2-2l10,10L2,20z"%20fill="%23c8c7cc"/></svg>');
    padding-right: 32px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 14px center;
    background-size: 14px 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> add the below code in the sass file wherever required-[from here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-arrow-forward-not-showing-up-for-button-ion-item/42922/9?u=cliffymk)

```
// BEGIN HACK --------------------------------------------------------
// I've copied this style from the iOS settings.  For some reason, the
// Android defaults do not have a right arrow on active list items that
// can be clickable.  This seems like a bad UX to me, so I'm adding
// it here for Android, even if it's not standard.

$icon-detail-push-background-svg:    "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 12 20'><path d='M2,20l-2-2l8-8L0,2l2-2l10,10L2,20z' fill='fg-color'/></svg>" !default;
$item-md-detail-push-color:          $list-md-border-color !default;

@mixin md-detail-push-icon($fg-color) {
  $svg: str-replace($icon-detail-push-background-svg, 'fg-color', $fg-color);
  @include svg-background-image($svg);
}

button.item:not([detail-none]) .item-inner,
a.item:not([detail-none]) .item-inner,
.item[detail-push] .item-inner {
  @include md-detail-push-icon($item-md-detail-push-color);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right (15px - 2) center;
  background-size: 14px 14px;
  padding-right: 32px;
}
// END HACK -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: better you use <ion-list> </ion-list>